# find, collect duplicates in list of lists/sets

Tags: python, list, unique

In Python, I have a list of tuples and a list of integers with the same length, e.g.,

```
a = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 66],
    [2, 3]
    ]

b = [
    1,
    31,
    31,
    44
    ]
```

The k-th entry in `a` can thought of as being associated with the k-th entry in `b`.

The entries `[3, 2]` and `[2, 3]` are really the same for me, and I'd like `a` uniquified with that in mind. Also, I would like a list of entries of belonging to the new unique list. For the above example,

```
a2 = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 2],  # or [2, 3]
    [4, 66]
    ]

b2 = [
    [1],
    [31, 44],
    [31]
    ]
```

`b2[0]` is `[1]` since `[1, 2]` is associated with only `1`. `b2[1]` is `[31, 44]` since `[2, 3]` (which equals `[3, 2]` is associated with `31` and `44` in `a`.

It's possible to go through `a` entry by entry, make each 2-list a frozenset, sort it into a dictionary etc. Needless to say, this doesn't perform very well if `a` and `b` are large.

Any hints on how to handle this smarter? (List comprehensions?)

Comment: How does b2 come about? Also `set(map(frozenset, a))` would be pretty efficient

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Clarified that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to maintain order and group I don't think you won't get much better than grouping with an *OrderedDict*:

```
from collections  import OrderedDict
a = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 66],
    [2, 3]
    ]

b = [1, 31, 31, 44]
d = OrderedDict()
for ind, f in enumerate(map(frozenset, a)):
        d.setdefault(f, []).append(b[ind])

print(list(d), list(d.values()))
```

Which would give you:

```
[frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({66, 4})] [[1], [31, 44], [31]]
```

if order seen is irrelevant, use a *defaultdict*:

```
from collections  import defaultdict
a = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 66],
    [2, 3]
    ]

b = [1, 31, 31, 44]
d = defaultdict(list)
for ind, f in enumerate(map(frozenset, a)):
        d[f].append(b[ind])

print(list(d), list(d.values()))
```

Which would give you:

```
 [frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({66, 4})] [[1], [31, 44], [31]]
```

If you really want lists or tuples:

```
print(list(map(list, d)), list(d.values()))
```

Which would give you:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [66, 4]] [[1], [31, 44], [31]]
```

For python2, you should use `itertools.izip` and `itertools.imap` in place of map and zip.

Comment: The `defaultdict` example is missing a `b`(`[ind]`) in the loop.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer, indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For a:

```
a = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 66],
    [2, 3]
    ]

a_set = {frozenset(i) for i in a}
a2 = list(list(i) for i in a_set)
print(a2)
# -> [[66, 4], [1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Not sure what you're looking for with b.

Edit: That makes more sense. @PadraicCunningham's answer is spot-on.